# How do I align the last bit of text to the right- neatly in a column - on a ListBox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

The code I have is:

```pascal
ListTab := IntToStr(92 - Length(ADOqry['Song']));
ListBox.Items.Add(IntToStr(Track) + #9 + ADOqry['Song'] + Format('%' + ListTab + 's', [SongLength]));
```

My output looked like this

[image]

I would like the last column to flow under 00:14.

Comment: probably start by using a fixed-length font such as Courier New and make sure `SongLength` is trimmed

Comment: What do you mean by "trimmed"?

Comment: @Ayaaz meaning, it has no leading or trailing whitespace in it. See [`SysUtils.Trim()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Trim) and [`TStringHelper.Trim()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Trim)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are attempting, you would have to use a mono-spaced Font for your ListBox, so that all of the characters have the same width and can thus be lined up the way you are attempting.  But, you are not using a mono-spaced font, you are actually using a variable-width Font instead, so each character has a different width.  That is why things are not lining up the way you want.

If you are using VCL, you really should not be using a `TListBox` at all for this task.  Use a multi-column `TListView` instead. Set its `ViewStyle` property to `vsReport`, add 3 columns to its `Columns` property and set their `Width`s as desired, and then you can populate each column with your values as needed, eg:

```pascal
var
  Item: TListItem;

Item := ListView.Items.Add;
Item.Caption := IntToStr(Track);
Item.SubItems.Add(ADOqry['Song']);
Item.SubItems.Add(SongLength);
```

If you are using FMX instead, you can use a `TListBox` to display data the way you describe (though you really should use `TListView` instead).  Set the ListBox's `DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle` property to `'listboxitemrightdetail'` (or any style that displays an item's `Detail` how you want), and then store your `SongLength` string in the `TListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail` property of each ListBox item:

```pascal
var
  Item: TListBoxItem;

Item := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox);
Item.Text := IntToStr(Track) + #9 + ADOqry['Song'];
Item.ItemData.Detail := SongLength;
ListBox.AddObject(Item);
```

See the following tutorial on Embarcadero's website:

[Using ListBox Components to Display a Table View](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_(iOS_and_Android))

Comment: It says TListItem does not contain a member named Caption and SubItems

Comment: @Ayaaz are you using FMX? I assumed VCL. You did not say which framework you are actually using. FMX's `TListView`/`TListItem` are *very different* than VCL's. It is important to state which framework you are using when asking questions, as it affects the kind of answers that will solve your issues

Comment: Sorry it's the first time I asked a question. I am using a Multi Device Application

Comment: @Ayaaz Multi-Device projects use FMX, not VCL.  I have updated my answer to include info for FMX.